# AnyChart on Android: Format x-Axis values

Tags: java, android, number-formatting, decimalformat, anychart

I am currently working with AnyChart on Android for the first time. The data is displayed correctly and everythings working so far. But I cannot format the values on the x-Axis.

I tried to use

```
cartesian2.xAxis(0).labels("{%Value}{numDecimals:2}");
```

But it does not have any effect. I just want two decimal digits. I did not find any solution online as most of the documentation is about JS.

EDIT:

```
 APIlib.getInstance().setActiveAnyChartView(brightplot);

        List<DataEntry> brightnessdata = createSeries(maxBrightnessRow);


        Cartesian cartesian2 = AnyChart.column();

        cartesian2.data(brightnessdata);

        cartesian2.title("Intensitätsverteilung");

        cartesian2.yScale().minimum(0d);
        cartesian2.yScale().maximum(255);

        cartesian2.xAxis(0).title("Ort [cm]");

        cartesian2.yAxis(0).title("Intensität");

        cartesian2.xScroller(true);
        cartesian2.xZoom(true);
        cartesian2.yAxis(0).labels(false);

        cartesian2.xZoom().setToPointsCount(1500,false, null);
        cartesian2.xAxis(0).labels().format("{%Value}{decimalsCount:2}");

        brightplot.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        brightplot.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        brightplot.setZoomEnabled(true);
        brightplot.setChart(cartesian2);
        brightplot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that x values should have "number" type, so to make it all work, please write the following line:
`chart.xAxis().labels().format("{%value}{type:number, decimalsCount:2}");`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `format()` function and formatting parameters which are defined as tokens for it.
Try the following line:

```
cartesian2.xAxis(0).labels().format("{%Value}{decimalsCount:2}");
```

This should work!

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it is still not working. I will edit my question to show more code.

Comment: What kind of data do you apply for the xAxis? Numbers or ['A', 'B', 'C'] like?

Comment: I apply numbers and they often have a lot of decimal digits.

Comment: Please, can you share with us at least one row of your data? I will reproduce the issue using your data format and code. The chart is cartesian, it means that if the X value is '12.1231', for example, it will show exactly this string without truncating digits. Just like in this sample - https://playground.anychart.com/aG9KK07w

Comment: Thank you. That is the issue. My data look pretty much like the data in the example code. I use a picture as an input and I want to plot the brightness of each pixel. Furthermore I transform the discrete pixel values into cm, therefore I have a lot of decimal digits. Is there another type of bar chart where I can format the x-Axis?

Comment: Every chart type in the AnyChart library supports formatting xAxis labels. I guess there's a detail we can miss. Please, can you contact us at support@anychart.com? A screenshot of your current chart and a few rows of data will give us enough information to reproduce the issue and suggest a solution. I'm sure your requirements can be met.

Comment: Find the necessary information about the types of values in this article: https://docs.anychart.com/Common_Settings/Text_Formatters#type